# Code for background plot between candles and Ma

Tags: plot, background, pine-script, pine-script-v5, candlesticks

I wonder if someone has a piece of pinescript code that plot the Background between the candles and the (pink) 200 SlowMa.

[image]

I was looking to do a background plot as the attached picture is showing.

But, cannot  find something like that atm, I tried to do that from de Tradingview documents but no luck till now :( could kindly someone point me out on any help on this, it will be great and I will be grateful so much!

Trying to code a plot the Background between the candles and the (pink) 200 SlowMa.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ma = ta.sma(close, 200)
close_plot = plot(close, color= color.new(color.white,100))
ma_plot = plot(ma, linewidth = 2)
fill(close_plot, ma_plot, color = (close > ma ? color.blue : color.gray))
```